# JavaScript - Expressão regular para formatar valores em real

Tags: javascript, regex

Olá, estou estudando expressões regulares e tentando fazer uma função para formatar valores. A ideia é receber um valor e retornar ele formatado.
Exemplo:

- 400.00 --> 400,00
- 150000.00 --> 150.000,00
- 1500.00 --> 1.500,00

A solução que cheguei foi esta:

```
priceFormat(value){
    let price = value.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace('.','')
    price = price.replace(/(\d{2})/, '$1,')
    price = price.replace(/(\d{3}(?!$))/g, '$1.') 
    return price.split('').reverse().join('')
}
```

Eu decidi inverter a string para formatar ela de trás para frente, parecia mais fácil. Acredito que deve ter uma maneira mais interessante de fazer essa tarefa, usando uma regex talvez, alguma ideia?

Comment: O parâmetro`value` vai apenas receber o tipo [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) ou também pode ser passado o tipo [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)? Pergunto por que quero saber se o que for passado no parâmetro pode ou não ser considerado que o parâmetro sempre será convertido em `Number`.

Comment: Pode ser String, tanto que a primeira coisa que fiz foi converter porque ele vem como Number

Comment: Não poderia só substituir (ponto) '.' por ',' (virgula)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou postar uma alternativa ao regex.

É referente à uma função nativa do javascript [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```
const valor = 1542;

const currencyBRL = (value) => {
  const formattedValue = value.toLocaleString(
    'pt-BR', 
    { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }
  );

    return formattedValue;
};

console.log(currencyBRL(valor)) // R$ 1.542,00
```

Comment: ótimo, não conhecia essa função, é até melhor do que usando regex, muito obrigado!